# Яке походження назви села "Свидники"?

Tags: значення-слів, етимологія, іменники, власні-назви

Проїжджаючи через Волинську область, зацікавило походження села [Свидники](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8), що розташоване там. Зазирнула в **ЕСУМ**, однак подібної інформації не знайшла.

Отож що означає "Свидники / свидник"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Перш за все, таких населених пунктів є аж [4](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_(%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F)): в Польщі, Словаччині і два в Україні (1,2). Історично так склалося, що західна частина нашої країни входила в склад Речі Посполитої, і саме від польського слова "[świdwą](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dere%C5%84_%C5%9Bwidwa)" (див. [джерело](https://vod.tvp.pl/video/polska-z-miodkiem,swidnik-i-swidnica,25285660) - "**Chodzi o roślinę, nazywaną świdwą, czyli o dereń**"), або ж українською "[дерен-свидина](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0)", походять назви всіх цих населених пунктів.